# Montar uma tabela de produtos como vitrine em java jsp

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Estou com uma dificuldade em apresentar uma lista de produtos tipo vitrine usando *Java* e *JSP*.

Consigo obter os dados, mas não sei preencher essa tabela usando o `<c:forEach>`

Minha tabela teria essa estrutura:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${produtos}" var="p">
        <tr>
            <td> ${p.nome } </td> <td>${p.nome } </td> <td>${p.nome }</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Porém o que é exibido é:

```
**produto 1 produto 1 produto 1**
**produto 2 produto 2 produto 2**
**produto 3 produto 3 produto 3**
```

Queria que exibisse assim:

```
**produto 1 produto 2 produto 3**
**produto 4 produto 5 produto 6**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para escrever de 3 em 3 produtos você pode fazer algo neste sentido:

Usar um contador `varStatus`, por exemplo `contador`, pra saber qual o índice do `forEach`, dessa forma toda vez que o `contador.count` for divisível por 3 você fecha a linha atual e adiciona um nova linha na tabela.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${produtos}" var="p" varStatus="contador">
        <tr>
            <td> ${p.nome } </td>
        <c:if test="${contador.count % 3}">
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

No final você pode acabar com um `<tr>` a mais, deixando o seu HTML inconsistente, para resolver essa situação faça uma checagem `c:if` antes de escrever o novo `<tr>`, você deve checar se o contador é menor que o tamanho da lista.
Como não sei se você está usando array ou lista você pode checar o tamanho com `.length()` e `.size()` respectivamente.